# How to visualize a forest/multiple trees?

Tags: d3.js

So I started from an [mbstock "block"](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1062288) and created this [fork](https://gist.github.com/thegreatmichael/8156d9597a0966c136fb43ce3c39614a). I wanted to simply change it to have multiple trees being displayed. To be clear, these would be multiple trees that have within them connected nodes, but no connections between separate trees.

I attempted this by trying to just ignore the original root in the example dataset and simply starting from it's children.

I am suspicious of [this line](https://gist.github.com/thegreatmichael/8156d9597a0966c136fb43ce3c39614a#file-index-html-L60) in my fork (kept from original) because the comment says `// Restart the force layout.`

How can I get it to just let me draw multiple trees instead of "restarting"?

[Interactive version of original](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288)

[Interactive Version of my attempt](https://bl.ocks.org/thegreatmichael/8156d9597a0966c136fb43ce3c39614a)

Comment: this is looking promising: https://bl.ocks.org/thegreatmichael/9316025680da9e95e72ea38c919b8742